# Code Coverage and Regular Expressions (dotCover)

Tags: regex, unit-testing, nunit, code-coverage, dotcover

I am using dotCover to check my code coverage.
At one line i am using a regular expression to check if a given string is valid.

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(value, @"[a-zA-Z\-]"))
    throw new NullReferenceException("value");
```

I have created a unit test that checks if my code works as expected.

But dotCover doesnt recognize my code as covered. Sure because i dont 
test it with every possible (not matching) character.

What is a good solution for that problem?

Comment: use a negated character class `if (Regex.IsMatch(value, @"[^a-zA-Z-]"))`. If a character is not in the class (all except ascii letters and the hyphen), an exception is thrown.

Comment: good idea @CasimiretHippolyte!

Comment: It's more easy than describing all the string: `if (!Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^[a-zA-Z-]*$"))`. But note that you need to check if the string isn't empty if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check that the string doesn't contain a character that is not an ascii letter or an hyphen, you can use one of these patterns:

with a negated character class (search a character):

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(value, @"[^a-zA-Z-]"))
```

without (describe all the string):

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^[a-zA-Z-]*$"))
```

If you want to prevent empty strings too:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(value, @"[^a-zA-Z-]|^$"))
```

or

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^[a-zA-Z-]+$"))
```